# How should we disambiguate [autoplay]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

[autoplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autoplay) has 652 questions and this tag wiki:

> AutoPlay, a feature introduced in Windows XP, examines newly discovered removable media and devices and, based on content such as pictures, music or video files, launches an appropriate application to play or display the content.

However, all of the most recent questions are about general video/audio autoplaying (usually in browsers) instead. A [quick search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&q=%5bautoplay%5d%20and%20%5bwindows*%5d%20) suggests that only 26 questions actually match the tag wiki.

Any suggestions for what we should do with this tag?

Comment: wouldn't it work if we retagged those 26 questions with [autorun], and edited the tag description (which is copied 1:1 from wikipedia)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No specific disambiguation is necessary here. The disambiguation can be accomplished by the presence of other tags on the question.

The problem was the tag wiki for the [autoplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autoplay) tag, which was inappropriately specific (it was also inappropriately plagiarized from Wikipedia). I've updated the tag wiki excerpt to provide the much-needed usage guidance:

> For questions about using autoplay features in a programmatic context.
> NOTE: If your question is about Windows AutoPlay, also include the [windows] tag. If your question is about AutoPlay in a web browser, add a browser tag and possibly other tags relating to the web technologies you are using.

I cannot, of course, force people to follow it. But the situation would be no better if we were to split [autoplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autoplay) up into multiple discrete tags (say, [windows-autoplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-autoplay) and [browser-autoplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/browser-autoplay)). You'd still be lacking some way to enforce people to use the proper tag (and not recreate [autoplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autoplay)).

There was a [flash-autoplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash-autoplay) tag, with 7 questions to its name. Following the above logic, I've merged this into [autoplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autoplay) as well.